# TinyMCE - Upload images, media and documents to your own server

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I am using TinyMCE for publishing articles in some journalistic and cultural portals.

As for the media (images, audio, video, documents), everything will have to be uploaded and managed internally, without using external links to services such as YouTube and TinyPIC, which I have no control over to ascertain the permanence of the media.

I was already using the `images_upload_url` option for images but I cannot find a similar option for all other media or a general option that works for all media types.

For some current sites I am using the external [responsivefilemanager](https://www.responsivefilemanager.com/) plugin but I was hoping that in future releases of TnyMCE an internal option similar to `images_upload_url` would be integrated.

Is this an option I can't find or has it not yet been integrated and [responsivefilemanager](https://www.responsivefilemanager.com/) still needs to be used?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same question, turns out if you are using a paid plan for TinyMCE, you could use their TinyDrive plugin & a TinyCloud account.

This allows to upload images, files and medias, plus it better integrates with their tools (ie you have a nice UI to access uploaded files by your text editor)

It may answer your need! I give you the link to their documentation: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/tinydrive-introduction/. You have a nice example on this page, to try it :

- Click on the Upload icon and upload your video
- Click on Insert > Media > General
- Click on the Upload icon and here is your video that you can add to your text content

Have a great day,

Comment: I decided to use the `file_picker_callback` function and so far I am quite happy with it.

Comment: Did you manage to get video file uploads to go via a url like `images_upload_url`? I am trying to do the same, but can only get it to upload as base64 encoded data within the text, not as an actual upload via a url.